# How to manipulate string value of item %(Filename)

Tags: msbuild

I'm using [Bond](https://github.com/microsoft/bond), it takes a bond file in the root of the project and generates a C# file under the obj folder:

```
\
  Foo.bond
\obj\x64\Debug\net6.0\win10-x64\
  Foo_types.cs
```

I'd like to make both files visible in Visual Studio. I can do it easily if list each bond-cs pair individually:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\Foo_types.cs">
     <DependentUpon>Foo.bond</DependentUpon>
     <Link>Foo_types.cs</Link>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

But how can I include all of them using a wildcard/glob pattern, given the cs file name is slightly different and is prefixed with `_types`. How to drop it?

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\*_types.cs">
    <DependentUpon>??? %(Filename) ??? .bond</DependentUpon>
    <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference an Item's own metadata in an `Include`. But you can in an `Update`.

This example code starts with the .bond files to create the metadata.

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <BondFile Include="*.bond" />
      <BondFile Update="@(BondFile)">
        <GeneratedFile>$(IntermediateOutputPath)\%(Filename)_types.cs</GeneratedFile>
      </BondFile>
      <None Include="@(BondFile->'%(GeneratedFile)')">
        <DependentUpon>%(BondFile.Identity)</DependentUpon>
      </None>
      <None Update="@(BondFile->'%(GeneratedFile)')">
        <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Briefly

1. A collection of *.bond files is created.
2. The collection is updated to add a `GeneratedFile` metadata using the `Filename`.
3. The set of `GeneratedFile`s is `Include`d into `None` with the `DependentUpon` bond file.

   - Note that `@(BondFile->'%(GeneratedFile)')` is a transform, not batching. It is the set of `GeneratedFile` values.
4. Finally, `Update` the set of `GeneratedFile`s in `None` to create the `Link` metadata.

Comment: hi Jonathan, thanks for your answer! unfortunately it didn't work. the items show up but not one under another. i'll try to figure out why. or if you could take a look too.

Comment: You may need to list out the files in the project because Visual Studio may only be reading the static XML for the display in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: See [File nesting in Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022) which explains the  `.filenesting.json` file.